# Gamma regression with quantitative factors only

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model

Can I estimate a gamma regression model with continuous dependent variables only? I want to predict production levels with workforce, inventory level, and demand.

Comment: Workforce, inventory level, and demand sound like independent variables or predictors if you want to use them to predict.

Answer (score 1):

For a gamma generalized linear model, the response variable needs to be positive, continuous and possibly right-skewed. The covariates can be continuous or factors.

Is production levels a continuous variable or does it take values like low and high? In the latter case, a gamma GLM can't be used.

Comment: Production levels follows a gamma distribution.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful.  - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/161786)

Comment: @Bjr [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)